# How to count the number of characters in the marked (selected) region?

Tags: mark, characters, selection, counter

I know how to count the number of words.

How to count the number of characters in the marked (selected) region?

Comment: FYI, if you use library [Modeline Region](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLineRegion) (code: [`modeline-region.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/modeline-region.el)) then you can have the count shown in the mode-line whenever the region is active. Automatically updates as you change the region size.

Comment: Indeed, my modeline (which is some Doom modeline package thing)was showing it too! I need to pay attention to what Emacs already does for me in front of my eyes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command name `count-words` is a bit misleading. It shows the number of words. But, it also counts the number of lines **and** the number of characters.

An output illustration:

> Region has 1 line, 51 words, and 280 characters.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding like an idiot:

```lisp
(length (buffer-substring-no-properties START END))
```

If you want to know how many characters it contains, including whatever properties and space they take up, you can leave out the words "no properties".

Answer (score 1):

`M-x region-length` shows you the number of characters. It does this using:

```lisp
(abs (- (mark) (point)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `shell-command-on-region` (bound to `M-|`) passes the region to the standard input of any shell command you want. The output is sent to the echo area if it is short enough or to a buffer whose name is stored in the variable `shell-command-buffer-name` (whose value is `*Shell Command Output*` by default) - or you can call the command with a prefix argument to *replace* the region by the output of the command.

Since you can use `wc` from the shell to count (lines, words, characters), you can do that from emacs by selecting the region and then `M-| wc`. Or to uppercase the region: `C-u M-| tr a-z A-Z`, or to get an uppercase copy of the region in the output buffer: `M-| tr a-z A-Z`. You can probably easily come up with a dozen more.

There are emacs equivalents to those and many more and it is often better to use them, but I find `M-|` to be a useful tool in my toolbox. It lets me use shell commands I know well to do some things that might require some time and effort to research, were I to use native tools.